# Can't open port at GCP Firewall

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've installed cPanel on CentOS7 VM by using following commands:

```
sudo su root
clear
yum -y install perl
hostname vps.DOMAINNAME
cd /home 
curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest 
sh latest
```

Then I've got Network Manager error: `NetworkManager is installed and running`. Hence, I disabled Network Manager using following command.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Then I reinstalled cPanel using following command:

```
curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest
sh latest
```

Then, after installing cPanel, I've got some url `https://SERVERIP:PORT`, but click on this url gave me **`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`**.

So, I decided to open ports on the Firewall by creating a rule:

```
Name : allroute
Logs: On 
Network : Default
Priority: 1000
Direction : Ingress
Action on match : Allow
Targets : All instances in the network
Source filter : IP ranges
Source IP ranges : 0.0.0.0/0
Second Source filter : None
Protocal and ports : Specified protocals and ports 
tcp : 1-65535
udp : 1-65535
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

**To open HTTPS access** to your VM I'd recommend you go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Firewalls`** and select `Allow HTTPS traffic` and after that pres `Save` button.

**I do not recommend open access to all ports** `tcp : 1-65535`and `udp : 1-65535` at `All instances in the network`. To make your rule working you should change **`Priority`** like it described in the documentation [Creating firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules):

> Specify the **`Priority`** of the rule. **The lower the number, the higher the
>   priority**.

To override [Pre-populated rules in the default network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) you should use lower **`Priority`** than have existing rules.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Configuring network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags):

> Network tags are text attributes you can add to Compute Engine virtual
>   machine (VM) instances. **Tags allow you to make firewall rules and
>   routes applicable to specific VM instances**.

Also, **you don't need to use dedicated firewall on your instances** because they've already protected by GCP Firewall.

Comment: Hey @SerhiiRohoza I've opened HTTPS access but still its not working.

Comment: Have you configured SSL certificates to use HTTPS? If not, try to open HTTP by selecting `Allow HTTP traffic` and check  `http://SERVERIP:PORT`.

Comment: I have allowed both HTTP and HTTPS but still it is not working. I tried HTTP as well it is not working.

Comment: 1. Check if you have access to `http://SERVERIP` and `https://SERVERIP`. You should see some welcome page of your web server. 2. Check your web sever from VM `curl -I -L http://SERVERIP` and `curl -I -L https://SERVERIP`.

Comment: Do you still have an error?